# PC automatically booting into windows 10 in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have both windows 10 and ubuntu 16 installed on my system.

Lately the system is automatically booting to windows. To boot to ubuntu, I first have to pause startup by pressing escape and then boot into ubuntu.

I know that I have to change the boot order to Ubuntu  but am not able to do so and the grub customiser helps to change only the boot order in grub menu to the best of my knowledge.

What should I do? I am unable to find any way to change the boot order in bios

Comment: What is the make and model number of your computer?

Comment: It is HP Envy series

Comment: Could you provide the `/etc/default/grub` content to your question?

Comment: HP has a number of Envy series computers.  They even have printers with the same name stamp.  Can you check your computer for more details such as the model number?  I see a number of desktops and Laptops, but would like to minimize time by going to your specific model.

Comment: @rjmessibarca The OP isn't having a problem with Grub.  He's having a problem with his BIOS.  He needs to set the BIOS to boot to Grub automatically rather than him having to manually choose Grub each time the computer starts.

Comment: @SanLinNaing http://pastebin.com/EY7ifiiP

Comment: @L.D.James Please wait a minute...I will try

Comment: @rjmessibarca Could you support also the image of boot screen list when you choose to boot Ubuntu? Because you need to change `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to the Ubuntu boot order number according to this [guide](https://launchintolinux.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/how-to-change-the-default-os-in-an-ubuntu-dual-boot-setup/).

Comment: @L.D.James Product name: HP Envy 15 notebook PC    Serial number:5CD437764W   http://imgur.com/bTizynL

Comment: @SanLinNaing The link that you gave is not of use to me. I don't wan't to change the default OS "in the grub menu". I want my PC to boot to Ubuntu so as to show me the grub menu

Comment: @rjmessibarca you said *"What should I do? I am unable to find any way to change the boot order in bios"*. **BIOS** only can change the boot order of multi disk such as HDD 1, HDD 2, USB1 like that. If you install OS on different media, you can change boot order in BIOS. But if you install 2 OS in one HDD, only boot loader can change boot order not BIOS. My suggestion is you should find how to configure boot loader in dual boot nature.

Comment: @rjmessibarca Bare with me for a few more minutes.

Comment: @L.D.James Sure and thanks for the help...been trying for the past 2 days

Comment: Can you tell me what you see in the BIOS when you do these steps: `Boot Options -> UEFI Boot Order > OS boot Manager`?  What options do you see under the `OS Boot Manager`?  If you see `Ubuntu`, then select that one and save the settings and reboot.  If you don't see that I'll check something different.

Comment: @Please wait a minute

Comment: @L.D. James Thanks a lot....It worked....Please post the above aa answer so that I may accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by going into the

```
BIOS -> UEFI Boot Order > OS Boot Manager
```

The exact wording will vary on different computer makes and models.

Now look for the `Ubuntu` entry.  Select that one and save the settings.